# Using a logic matrix to select values from another matrix (R)

Tags: r, logic

I have two dataframes with identical dimentions (18.000 rows, 42 cols) called cor and pval. cor contains correlation values, pval contains the pvalue associated with the correlation value at the same position.

I have been trying to create a new df containing only the cor values with a pvalue below a certain threshold (0.05). cor associated with pvalues above this threshold should be returned as "NA".

my tries sofar:

```
sign<-cor[pval<0.05]
sign<-cor%>%which(cor<0.05)
```

I'm considering creating logic vectors by column and looping through the dataframe, but that seems very clunky.
Any suggestions on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `cor` and `pval` have same dimension we can do :

```
cor[pval > 0.05] <- NA
```

to turn `cor` values to `NA` where `pval` is greater than 0.05.

Comment: That is simpler than I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `replace`

```
replace(cor, pval > 0.05, NA)
```